# Latex Math equation format going wrong

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write the following equation into latex but it bugs out. I have linked what i am trying to, the result of it in latex and the code.

Expected:  [image]

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
Lev(x,y)\begin{cases}
& max(i,j){  if } \qquad  if min(i,j) = 0\\ 
& min\begin{cases}
& \text{ Lev(i-1, j ) + 1  }  \quad  \\ 
& \text{ Lev(i-1, j ) + 1  }  \quad  other wise\\ 
& \text{ Lev(i-1, j ) + 1  }  \quad  \\ 
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Works for me. Did you properly enter math-mode (surround it by `\[ your code here \]`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

Aside: Note the use of `\min` and `\max` as well as the definition of `\Lev` as a "math operator".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lev}{Lev}
\begin{document}
\[
\Lev(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
  \max(i,j) & \text{if $\min(i,j) = 0$}\\[1ex] 
  \min\begin{cases}
     \Lev(i-1, j ) + 1  \\ 
     \Lev(i-1, j ) + 1  \\ 
     \Lev(i-1, j ) + 1    
\end{cases} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```